# Gutenberg Blocks with Timber and ACF Flexible Content

Tags: twig, block, advanced-custom-fields, timber, wordpress-gutenberg

We're creating a block.twig template as per: 
https://timber.github.io/docs/guides/gutenberg/#how-to-use-acf-blocks-with-timber
to use ACF Flexible Content Field Types to create Gutenberg Blocks.

For reference the following sample code would be for Repeater Field Types:

```
{% for field in fields.repeater %}
    Title: {{ field.title }} <br/>
    Url: {{ field.url }}
{% endfor %}
```

which we tested and seems to work fine.

What would be the equivalent using Flexible Content fields?

Thanks.

Comment: Why the downvote ???
What could possibly be wrong with this question? Is there something I didn't explain properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Rafael they're a little more complicated, just need to handle them like arrays. Let's pretend your Flexible Content field is called `my_fc_field` inside of it. You created 2 layouts, each has a single text field, one called `tf_one`, the other `fc_two`

```
{% for subfield in fields.my_fc_field %}
    Layout name: {{ subfield.acf_fc_layout }}
    Text Field Value: {{ subfield.tf_one ? subfield.tf_one : subfield.tf_two }}
{% endfor %}
```

doing a `{{ dump(fields.my_fc_field) }}` should make it clear what's inside there that you can manipulate/output

Comment: Works great @Jared. Much appreciated the time taken to explain it in detail. This should be added to the Timber documentation. 

Just a word of caution though: ACF 5.8.0-beta v4 fails to render it in the editor. Advise to stick to v3 for now